# Python3.4 : OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python, linux, memory, memory-leaks, multiprocessing

I am initializing a bunch of multiprocessing arrays that are 1048576 by 16 long in the file dijk_inner_mp.py:

```
N1=1048576
DEG1=16
P1=1
W = [[0 for x in range(DEG1)] for x in range(N1)]
W_index = [[0 for x in range(DEG1)] for x in range(N1)]
u = multiprocessing.Array('i',range(P1))
D = multiprocessing.Array('i',range(N1))
Q = multiprocessing.Array('i',range(N1))
l = [multiprocessing.Lock() for i in range(0,N1)]
```

After the initialization I create P1 number of processes that work on the allocated arrays. However, I keep running into this error on execution:

```
File "dijk_inner_mp.py", line 20, in <module>
    l = [multiprocessing.Lock() for i in range(0,N1)]
  File "dijk_inner_mp.py", line 20, in <listcomp>
    l = [multiprocessing.Lock() for i in range(0,N1)]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 66, in Lock
    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 163, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 60, in __init__
    unlink_now)
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

I have tried increasing the swap file size to say a few Gb after seeing some other questions about the issue, but that didnt seem to help. I also reduced the size to 131K from 1M and ended up with the same error. Any ideas on how to circumvent this issue?

Comment: what does `cat /proc/swaps` output?

Comment: Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda1                               partition       3298300 42496   -1

Comment: Its creating an array of locks. If I remove this then the error comes up on say Q = multiprocessing.Array('i',range(N1)) or any other array

Comment: I am able to run a similar code in C/C++, which means that the amount of memory is definitely not a problem. Something seems to be limiting the memory python processes can use, and hence it fires this assertion.

Comment: You're right I made a mistake running the code,   I get an error on the around the `65112` lock  every time

Answer (score 2):

Every instance of `multiprocessing.Lock()` maps a new semaphore file in `/dev/shm/` into memory.

[`man mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

> **ENOMEM** The process's maximum number of mappings would have been exceeded.

(Errno 12 is defined as `ENOMEM`.)

The system's maximum number of mappings is controlled by the kernel parameter `vm.max_map_count`; you can read it with `/sbin/sysctl vm.max_map_count`. Without much doubt you will see that this value on your system is clearly lower than the number of locks you want to create.

For ways to alter `vm.max_map_count` see e. g. this [Linux Forums thread](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/131557-what-maximum-number-mmaped-areas.html).